# Pandas calculate max possible rolling_mean up to window size

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to recreate the smoothing functionality of the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acorn&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cacorn%3B%2Cc0) using Pandas' rolling_mean function. Everything is great except for the last N rows (where N is equal to the window size chosen) result in NaN.  I understand why the NaN exists, but I'm wondering if there is a way to force Pandas to calculate the last N rows with the maximum window size possible.

Starting DataFrame:

> ```
>       y    mc    vc     g            freq
> 0   1980  2110   891  acorn  0.0000006816639806737
> 1   1981  2493   925  acorn  0.0000007869870441530
> 2   1982  1970   969  acorn  0.0000006058489961744
> 3   1983  1974   942  acorn  0.0000005869087043278
> 4   1984  2265   962  acorn  0.0000006284175013608
> 5   1985  2331  1002  acorn  0.0000006287865167972
> 6   1986  2288  1036  acorn  0.0000005938515224444
> 7   1987  2975  1081  acorn  0.0000007639327989758
> 8   1988  2562  1164  acorn  0.0000006201948589259
> 9   1989  2773  1271  acorn  0.0000006308818219374
> 10  1990  3230  1449  acorn  0.0000006736596925364
> 11  1991  3984  1279  acorn  0.0000008445218584394
> 12  1992  2908  1349  acorn  0.0000005616418361769
> 13  1993  3511  1522  acorn  0.0000006673125583208
> 14  1994  3623  1709  acorn  0.0000006391704741358
> 15  1995  3836  1760  acorn  0.0000006497943728333
> 16  1996  4304  1910  acorn  0.0000006909335126709
> 17  1997  4107  1954  acorn  0.0000006390261435505
> 18  1998  4469  1993  acorn  0.0000006660007460970
> 19  1999  4494  2141  acorn  0.0000006233081676193
> 20  2000  4827  2304  acorn  0.0000006135668877077
> ```

When I do this:

```
df['freq_average'] = pd.rolling_mean(df['freq'],5,min_periods=0,center=True)
```

I get this result:

> ```
>       y    mc    vc     g            freq              freq_average
> 0   1980  2110   891  acorn  0.0000006816639806737  0.0000006531021239145
> 1   1981  2493   925  acorn  0.0000007869870441530  0.0000006446377522759
> 2   1982  1970   969  acorn  0.0000006058489961744  0.0000006595496331134
> 3   1983  1974   942  acorn  0.0000005869087043278  0.0000006551768804259
> 4   1984  2265   962  acorn  0.0000006284175013608  0.0000006527473745770
> 5   1985  2331  1002  acorn  0.0000006287865167972  0.0000006546484943915
> 6   1986  2288  1036  acorn  0.0000005938515224444  0.0000006694537560066
> 7   1987  2975  1081  acorn  0.0000007639327989758  0.0000006489678280088
> 8   1988  2562  1164  acorn  0.0000006201948589259  0.0000006545554245675
> 9   1989  2773  1271  acorn  0.0000006308818219374  0.0000006593064945501
> 10  1990  3230  1449  acorn  0.0000006736596925364  0.0000006612498465021
> 11  1991  3984  1279  acorn  0.0000008445218584394  0.0000006668995733997
> 12  1992  2908  1349  acorn  0.0000005616418361769  0.0000006710063571366
> 13  1993  3511  1522  acorn  0.0000006673125583208  0.0000006621034432386
> 14  1994  3623  1709  acorn  0.0000006391704741358  0.0000006623864713016
> 15  1995  3836  1760  acorn  0.0000006497943728333  0.0000006608123863716
> 16  1996  4304  1910  acorn  0.0000006909335126709                    NaN
> 17  1997  4107  1954  acorn  0.0000006390261435505                    NaN
> 18  1998  4469  1993  acorn  0.0000006660007460970                    NaN
> 19  1999  4494  2141  acorn  0.0000006233081676193                    NaN
> 20  2000  4827  2304  acorn  0.0000006135668877077                    NaN
> ```

So what I'm looking for is a way to calculate the above results, but then have index 16 (in this case) calculated with window size of 4 (instead of the original 5), index 17 calculated with a window size of 3, and so on.

If you look at the results from the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acorn&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cacorn%3B%2Cc0), the index 16-20 should result in the following:

> ```
>       y    mc    vc     g            freq                 freq_average
> 16  1996  4304  1910  acorn  0.0000006909335126709        0.0000659528
> 17  1997  4107  1954  acorn  0.0000006390261435505        0.0000638973
> 18  1998  4469  1993  acorn  0.0000006660007460970        0.0000648639
> 19  1999  4494  2141  acorn  0.0000006233081676193        0.0000645971
> 20  2000  4827  2304  acorn  0.0000006135668877077        0.0000647105
> ```

I've been banging my head against this for a day or so and have had no luck.  Any direction is much appreciated!

Comment: There might be a more straight forward and efficient solution, but have you tried to calculated those values by yourself? I mean, it's not hard to build an iterative method that will go from i=16 to i =20, calculating the average from i to 20 values

Comment: Even stranger, I get different numbers when I do your rolling_mean, and only 2 NaN lines. Can you check this again?

Comment: @Inox - Any pointers on the direction to go in with your suggestion?

Comment: @AndyHayden - Just re-ran everything in the iPython notebook and am getting the same results.

Comment: Now that I see, indeed, only the last 2 should be NaN, as you are using center = True (then it will average from previous 2 to next 2). And Python will automatically do what you need in the first rows (take the average of what's available) but won't do it at the bottom

Comment: @dumbbyte weird, my numbers are all different.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention, I have to agree with Andy Hayden, when he says only the last two lines should be NaN, as you are using center = True (then it will average from previous 2 to next 2).

And Python will automatically do what you need in the first rows (take the average of what's available) but won't do it at the bottom. The logic is to get 2 previous values and 2 next values if available.

So, to follow the logic of the top rows:

```
for i in xrange(2):
    index = i + 19
    df['freq_average'] = sum(df['freq'].iloc[index-2:21] / (20-index+3)
```

This will take the average of the set of two previous values (index -2) until the end (21). This is oriented to your specific problem. For different windows you need to adapt.

Comment: If I remove the min_periods=0 from df['freq_average'] = pd.rolling_mean(df['freq'],5,min_periods=0,center=True) I get a result similar to what you are referring to. Only for a window of 5, the first 5 results and the last five results turn up as NaN.  With that said, I am going to tinker with your answer and see if I can adapt it to handle an N sized window. I'll post back with findings!

Answer (score 0):

According to 'help(pd.rolling_mean)' setting min_periods=0 (as you did) should do what you are looking for. However, in pandas 0.14.1, there's a bug in the implementation of rolling_* functions that causes NaNs to be put at the end when using center=True. The bug report is at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6795 .